# Why is my taphold simplecontextmenu position wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, contextmenu

I am using a jQuery plugin called [simple-context-menu](https://github.com/joewalnes/jquery-simple-context-menu) for my jQuery mobile context menu. I am happy with it and prefer it over the jQuery Mobile context menus which possess (for me) far too much nested markup and requires many redundant CSS class tags. "Simple Context Menu" only requires a simple array which is why it is superior for my needs.

However, on right-click it works as intended, but when I try to utilise "taphold" instead of right click the menu appears in the wrong place (far up and to the right)

```
$(function() {
$('.touchableFile').contextPopup({
   title: 'File Options',
   items: [
    {label:'Go To', icon:'/images/txt.png', action:function() { alert('clicked 1') } },
    {label:'Rename', icon:'/images/txt.png', action:function() { alert('clicked 1') } },  
    {label:'Delete', icon:'/images/txt.png', action:function() { alert('clicked 2') } }
    ]
});
$(".touchableFile").on("taphold", function(e) { 
    $(this).triggerHandler('contextmenu'); 
}); 
});
```

How can I get taphold to implement the same mouseX mouseY as a real right click?

Answer (score 1):

`taphold` is a custom event that doesn't carry the `originalEvent` object. This object holds values of `.pageX` and `.pageY`. Therefore, you need to use the `touchstart` event to get `.pageX` and `.pageY` position values to use them later once `taphold` is triggered.

You need to do some minor JS modifications to *Context Menu*, as follows:

In the JS file, place the below code before this line `this.bind('contextmenu', function(e) {`. This code will retrieve X & Y position

```
var touchX, touchY;

this.on("touchstart", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    touchX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    touchY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
});
```

Then change

```
this.bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
    var menu = createMenu(e)
        .show();
    var left = e.pageX + 5,
        top = e.pageY;
```

to

```
this.on('taphold', function (e) {
    var menu = createMenu(e)
        .show();

    var left = touchX + 5,
        top = touchY;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/b4TxA/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1) Tested on iPhone 5 - Safari Mobile</sup>